# Can you use TAILS on a PC with no OS?

Tags: tails

Can I run TAILS on a PC from USB with no other operating system? Like if I factory reset a PC and didn't reinstall windows would tails work with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the computer doesn't need an OS installed, and doesn't even need a physical hard drive.